# Vlookup formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, formulas

I hope you can help. I have two sheets see below. What I am trying to do is bring in the **Customer Expense Id** in Column U from Sheet 1 into Column Y in the more colorful sheet 2 using the **Expense Request Number** available in both sheets

Both columns are formatted to general and my formula to me seems correct

```
=VLOOKUP(X10,'[Covance Original.xlsx]Sheet1'!$T$2:$U$573,2,)
```

But I keep getting #N/A's throughout the column. I know there definitely matches here.

The Expense request number is in column T of one sheet and X of the other

Sheet 1 Or Covance Original

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

I am at a loss as to why I am getting #N/A throughout the columns for a few entries sure but not the entire column

Any help is as always greatly apprecaited.

Comment: Try adding `0` or `FALSE` after that last comma??

Comment: Also, appears the formatting is different - One sheet is 6 digit and the other is 5, perhaps remove the leading 0 if this is the case or use `IF(LEFT(cell,1)="0",RIGHT(cell,5),cell)` to search or something (depends whether data only has 5 digit numbers affected with the leading 0. Just some suggestions to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup column and match cells are different formats. One a string and other a number. Its not ideal to look do this sort of vlookup but a work around would be...

=VLOOKUP(VALUE(X10),'[Covance Original.xlsx]Sheet1'!$T$2:$U$573,2,False)

Comment: Hi Aeneas McBurney BOO YAAH that worked perfectly thank you so much of the help. Much Respect from Dublin